# Winform C# : Set default value to particular column in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Winform C#:

I have 3 columns in dataGrid in form such as ID,Name,Date. I have to set particular value for Date column on each row on button click event.

I tried for Default property of datagrid but it will set default value when new row add to datagrid.

Thanks.

Comment: *I tried for Default property of datagrid but it will set default value when new row add to datagrid.* It's how it is supposed to work. Is you question is *How to set a value to all cells in a particular column in DataGrid(View)?*

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow Row in myGrid.Rows)
{
    Row.Cells[2].Value = DateTime.Now; // Sets the value of the third column
}
```

Do you mean something like this? This will iterate trough all the rows in your data grid and set the value of the third column to the current date/time.